# Is comparing double values using == deterministic

Tags: java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        BigDecimal previousOperationAmount = new BigDecimal(1149.35);
        Double requestedAmount = 1149.35;

        if (requestedAmount != previousOperationAmount.doubleValue()) {
            System.out.println("Hello 1");
        }

        if(!requestedAmount.equals(previousOperationAmount.doubleValue())) {
            System.out.println("Hello 2");
        }
     }
}
```

There are two ways to compare double values.. 
One is with != operator and one is with .equals operator. I understand that .equals is better way to compare. But here, != comparison is also not giving any error .

Is is ok to use != comparison for double values ?
Is != check for double values deterministic ?

Comment: Technically, yes and no. Yes, it is ok to compare `double` (but not `Double`, since two `Double` objects with the same value are not the same `Double` object) with !=. But since `double` is not absolutely precise, you are running into a whole lot of trouble, for example if comparing 1.00000000000000000001 to 1.0 (which can happen quite easily). So better ways include, for example, using something like `Math.abs( double1 - double2 ) > eps` (for a useful eps).

Comment: `!=` is deterministic, just like `equals`. Why don't you just check the documentation of `Double.equals` to find out ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz you meant `Math.abs( double1 - double2 ) <= eps` when checking equality, right? Otherwise, `5.01` and `4.13` would pass that check for any `eps` smaller than `1.0`

Comment: @Shark Since the question was about `!=`, I used `>`. For equality, correct, there you should check `<` or `<=` eps. In this case, assuming an eps of 1E-6, we would have `|5.01 - 4.13| > 1E-6` which is `true` (and thus both are not equal in regard to this eps). If you wanted to test for equals, you have to switch the comparison around, true.

Comment: Oh, and let's not forget that there's some auto-unboxing involved here, too, which complicates the whole thing by one more level ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is clearly specified in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Note that in most cases, for two instances of class `Double`, `d1` and
>   `d2`, the value of `d1.equals(d2)` is `true` if and only if
>
> ```
> d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue()
> ```
>
> also has the value `true`. However, there are two exceptions:
>
> - If `d1` and `d2` both represent `Double.NaN`, then the `equals` method returns `true`, even though `Double.NaN==Double.NaN` has the
>     value `false`.
> - If `d1` represents `+0.0` while `d2` represents `-0.0`,
>     or vice versa, the equal test has the value `false`, even though
>     `+0.0==-0.0` has the value `true`.

Comment: What about BigDecimal auto unboxing. Would that make any effect. Can you put that into consideration

Comment: There is no such thing as auto unboxing for BigDecimal.